# Can't understand particalur Big-O example in textbook

Tags: big-o, logarithm

So far understanding Big-O notation and how it's calculated is ok...most of the situations are easy to understand.  However, I just came across this one problem that I cannot for the life of me figure out.

Directions: select the best big-O notation for the expression.

```
(n^2 + lg(n))(n-1) / (n + n^2)
```

The answer is O(n).  That's all fine and dandy, but how is that rationalized given the `n^3` factor in the numerator?  `n^3` isn't the best, but I thought there was like a "minimum" basis between `f(n) <= O(g(n))`?

The book has not explained any mathematical inner-workings, everything has sort of been injected into a possible solution (taking `f(n)` and generating a `g(n)` that's slightly greater than `f(n)`).

Kinda stumped.  Go crazy on the math, or math referencing, if you must.

Also, given a piece of code, how does one determine the time units per line?  How do you determine logarithmic times based off of a line of code (or multiple lines of code)?  I understand that declaring and setting a variable is considered 1 unit of time, but when things get nasty, how would I approach a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-rigorous answer:

1. Distributing the numerator product, we find that the numerator is `n^3 + n log(n) - n^2 - log n`.
2. We note that the numerator grows as `n^3` for large `n`, and the denominator grows as `n^2` for large `n`.
3. We interpret that as growth as `n^{3 - 2}` for large `n`, or `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant.  So those types of implications can be made then?  That helps immensely.  Any thoughts about what type of code causes `lg(n)` or `lg(lg(n))` performance?

Comment: Logarithmic complexity often appears when you can perform recursive splits of the solution space. For example, binary search is `log_2(n)`.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind when I start reading that amazingly-large intro to algorithms book...hope for the future!  Thanks bright-star

Answer (score 2):

If you throw this algorithm into Wolfram Alpha, [you get this generic result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(n%5E2+%2B+ln(n))(n-1)+%2F+(n+%2B+n%5E2)):

[image]

If you expand (FOIL) it, you get (roughly) a cubic function divided by a quadratic function.  With Big-O, constants don't matter and the larger power wins, so you'd result with [something like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E3%2F(n%5E2%2Bn)):

[image]

The rest from here is mathematical induction. The overall algorithm grows in a linear-like fashion with respect to larger and larger values of n.  It's not *quite* linear so we can't say it has a Big-Omega of (n), but it does come fairly reasonably close to O(n) due to the amortized constant growth rate.

Alternatively, you could annoy mathematicians everywhere and say, "Since this is based on Big-O rules, we can drop the factor of n from the denominator and thus result in O(n) by simple division."  However, it's important in my mind to consider that this is still not *quite* linear.

Mind, this is a less-rigorous explanation than might be satisfactory for your class, but this gives you some math-based perspective on its runtime.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification.  I'm assuming, over time, developing great time-based programs becomes easier or more intuitive?  I'm tackling the CS field on my own time, just reading books and chugging along...soloing it gives me more thrills and a deeper understanding of the material.

Comment: Identifying the runtime of the algorithms you write is a vital skill, as it can often mean the difference between good- and poor-performing code.  It gets somewhat simpler over time with the ability to profile your code.

Comment: Good to know, looking forward to what lies ahead.  Thanks, Makoto